# Video-streaming Stopped is showing google colab while using video in YOLOV3 model

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

```
!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg /content/drive/My\ Drive/checking/yolov3.weights -dont_show -ext_output video.mp4 -i 0 -out_filename res.avi
```

I am trying to run a video.mp4 in google colab using Yolov3 for object detection but it is continuously showing Video-streaming stopped! as an error. I am stuck at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue on Google Colab running this code:

```
!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights test.mp4 -dont_show -i 0 -out_filename results.avi
```

I managed to solve it specifying the exact path of the input video:

```
!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights /content/test.mp4 -dont_show -i 0 -out_filename results.avi
```

Hope it solves your problem too!

Comment: add \ in front of every space in the path, otherwise the video-streaming stopped! f.i
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/some file.mp4  -> 
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/some\ file.mp4

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the paths of the input video or output video as variables, then you can use these variables in the python command if you add the prefix `$`.

Here's how:

```
input_video = /content/test.mp4
output_video = /content/results.avi

!./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights $input_video -dont_show -i 0 -out_filename $output_video
```